# Simple data catalog solutions for desktop

Tags: data, metadata, catalog

I need a simple data catalog to manage some datasets and to visualize metadata about them (descriptive statistics, variables’ description, …). Datasets are CSV files in several folders and some tables in an SQLite database, everything stored in a Mac desktop.

Which solutions exist? Preferably free and open-source.
The two mains I know are Ckan and Amundsen, but I find them difficult to setup and use. Do you know any simple software to manage this kind of task?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: What features do you need? How much may such software cost? What OS must it run on (I assume MacOS, as you mentioned data is stored on a Mac desktop)? Can you please **[edit]** that into your question? Thanks!